# Как исправить ошибку в коде Python?

Tags: python

Всем доброго времени суток. Помогите пожалуйсто исправить ошибку в коде.
Этот фрагмент кода я взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786068/how-to-avoid-http-error-429-too-many-requests-python) я хочу встроить его в свой парсер что бы сервисы гугл не блокировали мой ip во время прасинга. Но когда я его запускаю выходит ошибка

```
 in <module>
    autoretry_for=(ConnectTimeout, TooManyRequests,),
NameError: name 'ConnectTimeout' is not defined
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И в чём отличие от вашего [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1355299/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5)?

Comment: Ну я дополнил его в прошлый раз может быть  я не правильно изложил свой вопрос а так разницы нет.

Comment: Для изменения того, чего неправильно изложили, - существует кнопка "Править". Дубли или удаления с последующим пересозданием одного и того же здесь не приветствуются.

Comment: Я вас понял извините в следующий раз не буду так делать

Comment: Код в вопросе должен быть текстом, а не скриншотом

Comment: Спасибо за поддержку я уже нашел решение для этого кода и он работает.